# OpenCV installation and Java run on Mac

Tags: opencv

I have a java code that uses OpenCV. Right now I just have to try to run that code. My Mac doesn't have OpenCV. And I need to download 2.4.13 version of OpenCV. I downloaded certain things but I do not understand the exact steps to make it run with my java code. Can someone help me and tell the exact steps to install OpenCV 2.4.13 and run my java code with it?

Comment: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/ this can help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV installation on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671827/opencv-installation-on-mac-os-x)