# opencv installation via homebrew fails on mac os 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, homebrew

I tried to install openCV lib on mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks) via homebrew:

```
brew install --env=std opencv
```

Doing so I end up with the following errors:

```
==> Installing opencv
==> Downloading https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/opencv/opencv/tar.gz/3.4.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/3.4.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tar.gz/3.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/Username/Library/Logs/Homebrew/opencv/02.make:
                 ^
/tmp/opencv-20171227-56491-w05uzt/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/fixedpoint.inl.hpp:81:22: note: candidate function
CV_ALWAYS_INLINE operator double() const { return (double)val / (1LL << fixedShift); }
                 ^
/tmp/opencv-20171227-56491-w05uzt/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/fixedpoint.inl.hpp:82:22: note: candidate function
CV_ALWAYS_INLINE operator float() const { return (float)val / (1LL << fixedShift); }
                 ^
/tmp/opencv-20171227-56491-w05uzt/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:579:16: error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'typename fixedpoint64::WT' (aka '<anonymous>::fixedpoint64')
    dst[i] = res;
           ^ ~~~
19 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/src/resize.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [modules/imgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_imgproc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Until now I didn't found a solution for this problem. Any ideas how to fix it?

Update:

Building and installing openCV version 2.4 worked (see [OpenCV installation on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671827/opencv-installation-on-mac-os-x)).

Comment: By the look at that issue (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7606) opencv staff don't support older versions of os x. So I'd say your best chances are either updating os x or trying to build older opencv version from sources